# Stripe Flask request/response methodology

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I've created a Flask simple form and created a Plan at Stripe.com and it works just fine. I can subscribe to plan in development mode and it reflects payments on Stripe. Now further I need to sync real time with Stripe site to get plan expiration and other events. I understand that for the purpose I need to create a callback function to get stripe id and save it to database. I would prefer to save it to database than sessions. Please advise that how to create a callback route and save values from JSON api to database. Following is my code to subscribe and I need to show expiration and other events.

```
def yearly_charged():
    #Need to save customer stripe ID to DB model  
    amount = 1450

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email='test@test.com',
        source=request.form['stripeToken']
    )
    try:
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            customer=customer.id,
            capture='true',
            amount=amount,
            currency='usd',
            description='standard',
        )
        data="$" + str(float(amount) / 100) + " " + charge.currency.upper()
    except stripe.error.CardError as e:
        # The card has been declined
        body = e.json_body
        err = body['error']
        print
        "Status is: %s" % e.http_status
        print
        "Type is: %s" % err['type']
        print
        "Code is: %s" % err['code']
        print
        "Message is: %s" % err['message']


    return render_template('/profile/charge.html', data=data, charge=charge)
```

Template:

```
<form action="/charged" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Amount is 14.95 USD </label>
                <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="{{ key }}"
                    data-description="Yearly recurring billing"
                    data-name="yearly"
                    data-amount="1495"
                    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                    data-locale="auto">
                </script>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Models:

```
class Students(db.Model):
    __tablename__='students'
    .......
    student_strip_id = db.Column(db.String(45))
    .......
```

Need help to devise following function so I can set method to get response in proper way to save in db.

```
@app.route('/oauth/callback/, methods=['POST'])
    # This is where I guess I have to define callback function to get API data
    return redirect('/')
```

The objective here is to extract Stripe id, expiry event and other subscription notices from stripe API objects to save in Flask Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that the code you shared simply [creates a one-off charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), not a subscription (i.e. recurring charges). You should look into the [documentation for subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart) if you want to create automatically recurring charges.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to be notified of successful subscription payments. An [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded) event will be created for each successful payment. (Cf. [here](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/lifecycle) for more information about subscription events.)

With Flask, a webhook handler would look similar to this:

```
import json
import stripe
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    event_json = json.loads(request.data)
    event = stripe.Event.retrieve(event_json['id'])

    if event.type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
        invoice = event.data.object
        # Do something with invoice
```

Comment: Thank you you've been a great help.